# Android: How can sharedUserId(deprecated in API level 29) be safely removed from an app?

Tags: android

I am dealing with an app that has android:sharedUserId value in Manifest,
and there was an issue regarding permission triggered by this android:sharedUserId value.

While trying to solve the problem, I checked out that [anderoid:sharedUserId was deprecated in API level 29](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element) (Android 10).
So now I would really like to remove this sharedUserId from the application. (permission problem in API 29 + deprecated in API 29)
As I tested in debug mode, it seems that complete uninstall and reinstall is required after removal of sharedUserId... and It "seems" that there is not much problem else than that.
But I cannot assure that it is really safe to delete this property and release an update on market.
This [IssueTracker Thread](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/135968240) created in June, 2019 is about this issue, but does not give detailed instruction on how to remove sharedUserId safely from an application.
Would deleting android:sharedUserId without any other modification end up with a critical problem?
If so, does anyone know an appropriate way to remove sharedUserId from Manifest file and safely release an update version?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I just checked out the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element) again in original English version... and found out this sentence was omitted in Korean translation.

> Note that existing apps cannot remove this value, as migrating off a
> shared user ID is not supported.

So sharedUserId drives out problems in Android 10 (obviously in my case), and there is no way to remove it. Did I get it right?
If so... well... I find this very surprising... and disappointing...

Comment: Do you know what that sentence means? I don't understand it. Why can't they remove it? What apps can't remove the value? Those that are already installed? Meaning you can't update an app to remove that value, but if you uninstall it and install it updated, it works? Also, I was thinking maybe that would be tied to minSdkVersion (like, if it was to Oreo, sharedUserId would still work even on Pie or higher, but from what you said seems it's not that way... Damn).

Comment: Encounter the same issue - any way I can make an app successfully get updated in play store if its sharedUserId was removed?

Answer (score 0):

This wasn't possible, but Android introduced a solution for this in sdk 33. It's called the [android:sharedUserMaxSdkVersion](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#sharedUserMaxSdkVersion) attribute. It's only available in android 13.  The documentation says:

> The maximum device SDK version for which the application will remain in the user ID defined in sharedUserId. Used when the application wants to migrate out of using shared user ID, but has to maintain backwards compatibility with the API level specified and before.

So I think you should define: `android:sharedUserMaxSdkVersion="29"`. But I'm not completely sure yet how this option should be interpreted.

Comment: I guess though the question becomes, if a few apps were relying on sharedUserId to share the status of whatever, what then is the replacement for that ?